# manipulating in the viewport has suddenly become quite impossible

Tags: 3d-view

I suddenly started to get the following error message: 'your system does not use 3D hardware accelation. Blender requires a graphic driver with OpenGL 2.1 support'. So I searched the internet and installed opengl32.dll. Blender is now opening again, but I'm hardly able to manipulate in the viewport. Blender is very slow to respond whenever I zoom or rotate in the viewport. Does anybody know a solution?

Answer (score 1):

This really sounds like a driver issue. Maybe something got corrupted or deleted (it can happen that an antivirus, for example, deletes a critical component of a driver). You see, OpenGL usually is part of the GFX driver package for any graphics card because OpenGL is hardware-dependent and is integrated by the GFX card's maker. Just putting the file in there is not a solution--you're doing the equivalent of driving a car with a wheel missing.

For this reason, I recommend that you reinstall the current version or install the newest version of your graphics drivers. If you already have the newest, either try reinstalling or roll back to an older version if that is the cause (most likely it's not).

If you have an AMD card, download drivers here: https://www.amd.com/en/support

If you have an NVIDIA card, download drivers here: https://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx

If this doesn't work, you may need to uninstall the drivers first (to avoid left-over files from conflicting with the new ones). Otherwise, an update should suffice.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation. I have an NVIDIA card, but I'm not sure which 'product type' to select under NVIDIA Drivers Download in your link.  Would you happen to know how to find out which download would go with my computer?

Comment: Sure. Press Windows key + R to bring up the run prompt. Then type in "dxdiag". Go to display tab up top (it may be named "monitor" instead) and check what your graphics card is. If you have an integrated, then find the monitor tab that has the dedicated NVIDIA card. That's how you'll know the model.

Comment: Thanks for your swift reply. Unfortunately downloading the driver hasn't done the trick. How do I uninstall the drivers? I'm not sure where they are located on my computer and how to avoid deleting important files. Sorry for my lack of knowledge when it comes to computers...

Comment: Ok, update--I've deleted my previous comment: I did research and here's my suggestion: after you installed the graphics driver, reboot your computer if it wasn't done already. Then go back to Blender's folder and remove that opengl32 file. Now try to run it. The issue with this is that you're essentially running OpenGL as Blender works (emulation), rather than having it run natively from your graphics processor's end. I should have mentioned this deletion part. Let me know the results.

Comment: You are a hero! Thanks a lot. All is working fine again.

Comment: Great. I thought that may be the fix. Glad to be of help.